# How to reference or call a view controller written in Swift from another controller written in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an Objective-C project, and need hints on how to call a ViewController which is in Swift from another controller in Objective-C?

Comment: Create a `Objective-c Generated Interface Header` in your apps build setting. Now you can use this header to import you swift code in you Objective-C code and just use the view controller like you would any other.

Comment: How is posible to import a swift class?

Comment: This is NOT too broad.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Apparently it's [quite easy](http://ericasadun.com/2014/08/21/swift-calling-swift-functions-from-objective-c/).

1. You have to first make sure you're prepending your class declaration with `@objc` so that it's available to your Objective-C ones.

For example:

```
import Foundation

// Belongs to target 'TestProject'
@objc class SwiftController: UIViewController {

    //... truncated

}
```

2. Now you simply have to import the name of your *target* (that the swift controller belongs to), appended with `'-Swift.h'`—exposing its interface—like so:

   `#import "TestProject-Swift.h"`

Comment: no result, when i import a class #import "TestClass-Swift.h" doesen't find that class

Comment: You need to go in to your build settings and set the `Objective-c Generated Interface Header.`

Comment: @rckoenes doesen't work yet?

Comment: Make sure you're not importing the class and importing the **target** your class is in. So, if your class `TestClass` is in a project named `TestProject` (most likely with an auto-generated target called `TestProject`), then you would need to import `TestProject-Swift.h`. Remember, Swift files don't have headers.

Comment: do i need to mark initializers and view controller lifecycle methods as objc?

Answer (score -3):

Create a new file "YourAppName-Bridging-Header.h" and in this file you have to import "Your objective-C view controller.h"

Go to Build setting and search for bridging header and link with your birdging-header path.

Now you are able to write code in swift as usual.

Comment: I think OP is asking about accessing a Swift controller in an Objective C file.

Comment: You can use this either you have to use swift controller in objective C file or objective C controller in swift file.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. Don't you have to prepend the Swift classes with `@objc`?

Comment: You shouldn't make the header anyway. It is automatically generated with the proper settings. Making it yourself invites a lot of user error.